# Open big image of image thumbnail in next window(tab)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I show image thumbnails in the browser like this:
[image]

Now when I click on a thumbnail, a new window for that thumbnail is appearing blank. I want to display the big image for that thumbnail. I'm using an image control. How can I display the big image for that thumbnail?

If I display the thumbnail with this source:

> src="file:~/printImages/0150/21022013/0150_21022013_002_tn.jpg"

Then its big image source is exactly the same except for `_tn`:

> src="file:~/printImages/0150/21022013/0150_21022013_002.jpg"

Can I replace the last last section of the source from _tn.jpg to .jpg on click and then make the big image display in a new window?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can do something like this.  I have added the css class "bigClick" just to make the selection process cleaner for this example.

```
<img src="/printImages/0150/21022013/0150_21022013_002_tn.jpg" class="bigClick"/><br/>
<img src="/printImages/0150/21022013/0150_21022013_003_tn.jpg" class="bigClick"/><br/>
<img src="/printImages/0150/21022013/0150_21022013_004_tn.jpg" class="bigClick"/><br/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".bigClick").each(function(i) {
            var href = this.src.replace("_tn", "");
            $(this).wrap(
                $("<a>").attr("href", href).attr("target", "_blank")
            );
        });
    })
</script>
```